# Labelling R2 and p value in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add lm model coefs of two parallel modelling results onto the same ggplot plot. Here is my working example:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(100)
dat <- data.frame(
        x <- rnorm(100, 1),
        y <- rnorm(100, 10),
        lev <- gl(n = 2, k = 50, labels = letters[1:2])
        )

mod1 <- lm(y~x, dat = dat[lev %in% "a", ])
r1 <- paste("R^2==", round(summary(mod1)[[9]], 3))
p1<- paste("p==", round(summary(mod1)[[4]][2, 4], 3), sep= "")
lab1 <- paste(r1, p1, sep =",")

mod2 <- lm(y~x, dat = dat[lev %in% "b", ])
r2 <- paste("R^2==", round(summary(mod2)[[9]], 3))
p2 <- paste("p==", round(summary(mod2)[[4]][2, 4], 3), sep= "")
lab2 <- paste(r2, p2, sep =",")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, col = lev)) + geom_jitter() + geom_smooth(method = "lm") + annotate("text", x = 2, y = 12, label = lab1, parse = T) + annotate("text", x = 10, y = 8, label = lab2, parse = T)
```

Here is the promot shows:

```
Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : <text>:1:12: unexpected ','
1: R^2== 0.008,
```

Now the problem is that I could label either R2 or p value seperately, but not both of them together. How could I do to put the two results into one single line on the figure? 
BTW, any other efficienty way of doing the same thing as my code? I have nine subplots that I want to put into one full plot, and I don't want to add them one by one.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++  Some update ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Following @G. Grothendieck 's kind suggestion and idea, I tried to wrap the most repeatative part of the codes into a function, so I could finish all the plot with a few lines. Now the problem is that, whatever I changed the input variables, the output plot are basically the same, except the axis labels. Can anyone explain why? The following is the working code I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

set.seed(100)
dat <- data.frame(
        x = rnorm(100, 1),
        y = rnorm(100, 10),
        z = rnorm(100, 25),
        lev = gl(n = 2, k = 50, labels = letters[1:2])
        )
test <- function(dat, x, y){
fmt <- "%s: Adj ~ R^2 == %.3f * ',' ~ {p == %.3f}"

mod1 <- lm(y ~ x, dat, subset = lev == "a")
sum1 <- summary(mod1)
lab1 <- sprintf(fmt, "a", sum1$adj.r.squared, coef(sum1)[2, 4])

mod2 <- lm(y ~ x, dat, subset = lev == "b")
sum2 <- summary(mod2)
lab2 <- sprintf(fmt, "b", sum2$adj.r.squared, coef(sum2)[2, 4])

colors <- 1:2

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, col = lev)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = c(12, 8), label = c(lab1, lab2), 
    parse = TRUE, hjust = 0, color = colors) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors)
return(p)
} 

ggarrange(test(dat, x, z), test(dat, y, z))
```

Comment: These might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48912224/how-to-add-linear-lines-to-a-plot-with-multiple-data-sets-of-a-data-frame & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681895/ggplot2-issues-with-dual-y-axes-and-loess-smoothing

Comment: Thanks Tung, I also found stat_poly_eq to be very helpful. Unfortunately, it seems that  stat_poly_eq can't output p.value, so some other people used stat_fit_glance also.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here:

- `x`, `y` and `lev` are *arguments* to `data.frame` so they must be specified using `=` rather than `<-`
- make use of the `subset=` argument in `lm`
- use `sprintf` instead of `paste` to simplify the specification of labels
- label the text strings `a` and `b` and make them the same color as the corresponding lines to identify which is which
- the formula syntax needs to be corrected.  See `fmt` below.
- it would be clearer to use component names and accessor functions of the summary objects where available
- use `TRUE` rather than `T` because the latter can be overridden if there is a variable called `T` but `TRUE` can never be overridden.
- use `hjust=0` and adjust the `x=` and `y=` in `annotate` to align the two text strings
- combine the `annotate` statements
- place the individual terms of the `ggplot` statement on separate lines for improved readability

This gives:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(100)
dat <- data.frame(
        x = rnorm(100, 1),
        y = rnorm(100, 10),
        lev = gl(n = 2, k = 50, labels = letters[1:2])
        )

fmt <- "%s: Adj ~ R^2 == %.3f * ',' ~ {p == %.3f}"

mod1 <- lm(y ~ x, dat, subset = lev == "a")
sum1 <- summary(mod1)
lab1 <- sprintf(fmt, "a", sum1$adj.r.squared, coef(sum1)[2, 4])

mod2 <- lm(y ~ x, dat, subset = lev == "b")
sum2 <- summary(mod2)
lab2 <- sprintf(fmt, "b", sum2$adj.r.squared, coef(sum2)[2, 4])

colors <- 1:2

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, col = lev)) + 
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") + 
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = c(12, 8), label = c(lab1, lab2), 
    parse = TRUE, hjust = 0, color = colors) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colors)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck for your kind help. Now a new problem emerge, and can you also check why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, the problem's with the `parse = T` arguments to your `annotate` calls.  I don't think your strings need to be parsed.  Try `parse = F` instead, or just drop the parameter, as the default value seems to be `FALSE` anyway

Comment: If you don't use parse=TRUE then the strings won't be formatted. For example the 2 in R squared won't appear as a superscript but will appear as a circumflex followed by 2.