# How to plot dual-y axis using pivot_longer and vectors of different lengths?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph in ggplot using `pivot_longer` but I am struggling to figure out how I can add a second y-axis and plot another series. Some of my data is of different lengths so that is why I am using `pivot_longer` but I dont know how to accomodate that with a dual-y axis.

The error I keep getting is the following: "`Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (48): y`"

Any ideas how I could resolve this? The plot works fine when I comment out `geom_line(aes(y=na))+`

```
xstar = 0.85
x1 = c(0.87827, 0.91340, 0.92754, 0.92065, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.85643)      
x2 =  c(0.68152, 0.78534, 0.82775, 0.82965, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643, 0.85643)
x3 =  c(0.67141, 0.77874, 0.82259, 0.82487, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.77612, 0.85643)    
a = c(0.30000, 0.67141, 0.77874, 0.77874, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965, 0.82965)
b = c(0.95000, 0.95000, 0.95000, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.92754, 0.85643, 0.85643)
na = c(0, 28,  6, 57, 32, 24, 13, 92, 37, 32, 58, 17, 11, 40,  1)

acc = seq(from = 1, to = (length(a)), by = 1)

na[(length(a))] = NA
x1[(length(a))] = NA
x2[(length(a))] = NA
x3[(length(a))] = NA

totdat = tibble(acc,x1,x2,x3,b,a)
totdat
adjtotdat = pivot_longer(totdat, c(x1,x2,x3))
adjtotdat
```

```
pnas = ggplot(adjtotdat, aes(x = acc, y = value, color = name))
pnas + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=a,ymax=b),fill= "#CCCCCC", color= "#FFFFFF", alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y=na))+  
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0,ymax=a),fill= "#333333", color= "#FFFFFF", alpha=0.5)+  
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=b,ymax=1),fill= "#333333", color= "#FFFFFF", alpha=0.5)+ geom_line(size=1) + geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = a), color = "#336600", size = 1) + geom_point(aes(y = a), color = "#336600", size = 2)+
  geom_line(aes(y = b), color = "#006633", size= 1) +
  geom_point(aes(y = b), color = "#006633", size = 2)+
  annotate(geom = "text",x = 1+0.45, y= (min(c(a))-0.02), label = 'bold("Lower Threshold")', size = 3.5, parse = TRUE) +
  annotate(geom = "text",x = 1+0.45, y= (max(c(b)-0.02)), label = 'bold("Upper Threshold")', size= 3, parse = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,0.1),sec.axis = sec_axis(trans=~.*((70)), name="Number of Periods between Accidents")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,(length(a)),1)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = xstar, linetype ="Ex Ante Court Eff. Effort"), col = "green", size = 1.2)+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c(2), guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(color=c("green")))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue","red","purple","#006633","#336600"), 
                      limits = c("x1","x2","x3","b","a"), name="", 
                      labels = c("Driver 1", "Driver 2", "Driver 3", "Upper Legal Threshold","Lower Legal Threshold"))
```

Comment: Your first `ggplot` statement uses `adjtotdat` as the dataframe. When you add `geom_line` and declare a `y` value, it tries to line that up with your current `x`, which is `acc` of length 48. You have to either make `na` a dataframe and add that outside the `aes` in `geom_line` or make it length 48. I didn't check your other code but that's where the error comes from

Comment: What is `xstar`?

Comment: Thank you for the response. But isnt the length of ```acc``` 16 (after NA assignment)? When i use ```length(acc)``` I get 16 and when I use ```length(adjtotdat)``` I get 5 so thats why Im a little confused of what I should be extending to what

Comment: Sorry about that @Tung. Its a parameter I forgot to put in in the reprex

Comment: @NateRiver: You might want to rescale your axis. See these for examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/52704557/786542 &  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51458034/786542

Comment: `ggplot` didn't know where to draw `na` vector as x-axis values were missing. `na` didn't belong to `adjtotdat` so `ggplot` couldn't use  `acc` as x values. You need to create another data frame that has `na` as one of the columns or add `na` column to `adjtotdat`

Comment: I added ```na``` to ```totdat``` and then to ```adjtotdat```. The ggplot works now but the graph is very strange. I think the scales are very off